# Join two dataframes with limiting the rows of one dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark, join

I have two dataframes :

```
df1:
+--------------+---------------------+
|id_device     |tracking_time        |
+--------------+---------------------+
|20            |2020-02-19 02:37:45  |
|5             |2020-02-17 17:15:45  |
+--------------+---------------------+



df2
+--------------+----------------------+
|id_device     |tracking_time         |
+--------------+----------------------+
|20            | 2019-02-19 02:41:45  |
|20            |2020-01-17 17:15:45   |
+--------------+----------------------+
```

I want to get the following output :

```
+--------------+---------------------+------------------+
|id_device     |tracking_time        | df2.tracking_time |
+--------------+---------------------+------------------+
|20            |2020-02-19 02:37:45  |2019-02-19 02:41:45|
|5             |2020-02-17 17:15:45  |null               |
+--------------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

I tried the following code :

```
df1.registerTempTable("data");
    df2.createOrReplaceTempView("tdays");     
Dataset<Row> d_f = sparkSession.sql("select a.* , b.*  from data as a  LEFT JOIN (select  * from tdays ) as b  on b.id_device == a.id_device and b.tracking_time < a.tracking_time ");
```

I get the following output :

```
+----------------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------ -+
|id_device             |tracking_time        | b.id_device        |b.tracking_time     |
+----------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|20                     |2020-02-19 02:37:45 |20                  | 2019-02-19 02:41:45|
|20                     |2020-02-19 02:37:45 |20                  | 2020-01-17 17:15:45|
|5                      |2020-02-17 17:15:45 |null                |null                |
+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

What I want is to join the first dataframe with result of left join `ordered by df2.tracking_time desc limit 1`

I need your help

Comment: what you need is some kind of window over hte ID partition I'd say? Also, how do you decide on which of the two dtaes in df2 to choose?

Comment: I choose the older date

Answer (score 1):

Before the join, you can reduce `df2` to the minimum dates for each `id_device`:

```scala
val df1 = ...
val df2 = ...
val df2min = df2.groupBy("id_device").agg(min("tracking_time")).as("df2.tracking_time")
val result = df1.join(df2min, Seq("id_device"), "left")
```

`df2min` contains only a single row with the minimum date from `df2` per id. Therefore the left join will return the expected result.